# Add file to non accurate git repository

Tags: git, version-control, commit, branching-and-merging, git-push

I'm new to version control systems.

I'm currently working on a project on two computers : one at home and another one that doesn't belong to me. Using `git`, I usually push every time I end my session on the other computer. Last time I forgot to do that. Since I don't mind not having last edited files, I'm working on my computer without those files. I want to upload a file on the repository so that later on, when I log onto the other computer, I can simply add this new file to my non-pushed repo version and push them all together. What command would allow me to achieve this result ?

I'm pretty sure I'm not explaining properly so please tell me how I can make myself clearer. Every help appreciated

Comment: I suggest you read the first three chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). These will explain the basic commands that you will need to use from day to day. As you have time, read the rest of the book to get a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing here is the natural flow of development using version control systems. Here's the flow you're likely to encounter:

1. You work on your computer without the changes that you forgot to push from the other computer. You work some, and push changes to the same files that you have changes for on your other computer.
2. Once you get to that other computer, simply `git pull` to have the changes that you pushed earlier from a different machine.
3. Git will do a merge (default) or a rebase (that's another story) and that merge either goes well, or you are required to resolve conflicts if any.
4. You can now commit and push your local changes.